# Filter condition not working properly in my T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filter, multiple-conditions

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I have the following line of code in my query:

```
AND NOT (f.Name = 'ABC Ltd' and a.PackagePlanCode like 'CO%' and c.PropertyCode = 'BIC')
```

I need ALL of the conditions to stand. That is, f.Name must be equal to 'ABC Ltd' AND a.PackagePlanCode MUST start with 'CO...' and the PropertyCode MUST be 'BIC'.

I am seeing an erratic behavior in my query with the above line of code. A times, even if 2 of the conditions fit, it is excluding that record.

I have a record in my database which has the following:

Name = XYZ ltd

PackagePlanCode = COHB

PropertyCode = BIC

The above record should NOT have been excluded from my result set because it only has 2 criterias (namely PackagePlanCode and PropertyCode) that meet my filter and yet it is excluded from the result set.

Is there a better way to write this code so that I am sure that it is excluding records which only meet ALL 3 conditions mentioned therein?

Comment: In your copied code, there is "AND NOT" in front of the parentheses. So this changes the WHERE clause logic totally. Why don't you remove it all. Only the inside of the parentheses after WHERE

Comment: I have other conditions that exist after my WHERE clause. This is just one of them and here I am EXCLUDING records that meet these 3 criteria.

Comment: And do you mean in the result set, there are rows with matching these criteria? Could it be a collation issue, varchar or nvarchar related something?

Comment: In the result set, I am NOT seeing a record where the Name is something other than  ABC Ltd but which do have PackagePlanCode starting with 'CO...' and PropertyCode as 'BIC'.
To simplify I have a Record in my database which looks like this:
Name = XYZ ltd
PackagePlanCode = COHB
PropertyCode = BIC

The above record should NOT have been excluded from my result set because it only has 2 criterias (namely PackagPlanCode and PropertyCode) that meet my filter.
I hope I made it somewhat clearer.

Comment: @LukStorms I tested again by removing all the other filters in my query and kept this one. It still fails to show the record I mentioned above.

Comment: But you also join at least 2 tables. Could you perhaps include the FROM and the JOIN clauses to the question? Change the tablenames if you want.  Because such `AND NOT (.AND ... AND..)` works as one would expect, well besides the fact that it will also filter those where one of the columns is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended as a solution.
(I suspect the joins or something in the other conditions)

Just adding an example to show that the WHERE clause works as one would expect from it. If there are no NULLs anyway.

```
declare @T table (id int identity, num1 int, var1 varchar(30), var2 varchar(30), var3 varchar(30));

insert into @T (num1, var1, var2, var3) values 
(1,'Foo','Bar','Baz'),
(1,'Foo','Bar','CO Baz'),
(1,'Bar','Bar','CO Baz'),
(1,'Foo','Bar',null),
(1,'Foo',null,'CO Baz');

-- Query 1
select * from @T
where num1 > 0
and NOT (var1 = 'Foo' and var2 = 'Bar' and var3 like 'CO%');

-- Query 2
select * from @T
where num1 > 0
and NOT (coalesce(var1,'') = 'Foo' and coalesce(var2,'') = 'Bar' and coalesce(var3,'') like 'CO%');

-- Query 3
select * from @T
where num1 > 0
and IIF(var1 = 'Foo' and var2 = 'Bar' and var3 like 'CO%',1,0) = 0;
```

Query 1 returns

```
id  num1  var1  var2  var3
1   1     Foo   Bar   Baz
3   1     Bar   Bar   CO Baz
```

Query 2 & 3 return

```
id  num1  var1  var2  var3
1   1     Foo   Bar   Baz
3   1     Bar   Bar   CO Baz
4   1     Foo   Bar   NULL
5   1     Foo   NULL  CO Baz
```